# I get a Response error when trying to make a request to my Tastypie REST API using Python Social Auth

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I've created a REST API to signup using Facebook using:

- Django 1.7
- Python Social Auth 0.2.12
- Tastypie

It works when I use the PSA in my web views. But I try to request the API I get this error:

> AttributeError at /api/v1/social_sign_up/
>   **'Response' object has no attribute 'has_header'** Request Method:   POST Request
>   URL:  http://dev.midiacode.com:8000/api/v1/social_sign_up/ Django
>   Version:  1.7.4 Exception Type:   AttributeError Exception Value: 
>   'Response' object has no attribute 'has_header' Exception
>   Location: /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/midiacode_dj1.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/cache.py
>   in patch_vary_headers, line 148 Python
>   Executable:   /home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/midiacode_dj1.7/bin/python
>   Python Version:   2.7.5 Python Path:   ['/var/www/midiacode-api', 
>   '/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/midiacode_dj1.7/lib/python2.7', 
>   '/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/midiacode_dj1.7/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
>   '/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/midiacode_dj1.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
>   '/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/midiacode_dj1.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
>   '/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/midiacode_dj1.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7',  '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', 
>   '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
>   '/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/midiacode_dj1.7/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
>   Server time:  Fri, 18 Sep 2015 19:30:34 +0000

My request is: 
POST {{host}}/social_sign_up/

```
{
"provider":"facebook",   
"access_token":"CAAXAb1l2Bh4BAIxPoQYsz6BaWLl0muRLKHCycVhsYZAsd8ZB9TzsTcvsn5OtZCWe4N2bV2UYK4nLGy9VWA7JjhSmii3nfkZAkgphZAKypyYCcx9TQeGoWgIV7wuBj5HDyAmdregMztOub3Huzh5MYBAGxsZBwBQhJI1PC3I7M92VbWTiVvvKhfJQ9EYyPw4pqBUfTBwjpXhwZDZD"
}
```

My resource:

```
class SocialSignUpResource(BaseModelResource):

class Meta:
    queryset = MidiacodeUser.objects.all()
    allowed_methods = ['post']
    resource_name = "social_sign_up"
    always_return_data = True
    authentication = AnonymousAuthentication()
    authorization = Authorization()

def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
    provider = bundle.data['provider']
    access_token = bundle.data['access_token']
    strategy = load_strategy(request)
    uri = redirect_uri = "social:complete"
    if uri and not uri.startswith('/'):
        uri = reverse(redirect_uri, args=(provider,))
    backend = load_backend(strategy, provider, uri)
    user = backend.do_auth(access_token=access_token)
    if user and user.is_active:
        bundle.obj = user
        print bundle
        return bundle
    else:
        print "no user"
        raise HttpBadRequest("Error authenticating user with this provider")
```